# How to match an element to an object's list and return the object

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have an object model similar to this:

```
List<User> userList; //and each user contains list of address
List<Address>; 

class User {

    private Long id;
    List<Address> address;

    // getters & setters
} 

class Address {

    Long id
}
```

Now I need to find the user of which the id of the address is predefined, let's say `4`, from the `userList` from the Java Stream API.

Comment: What have your tried up to now?

Comment: you could accept the answer if it has helped you, see [here how to do it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Optional<User> user = userList.stream()
         .filter(x -> x.getAddress().stream().anyMatch(a -> a.getId() == 4))
         .findAny();
```

Comment: `4L` is already sufficient to get a `Long`, you don’t need `Long.valueOf(…)`. The better solution is to use `.anyMatch(a -> a.getId() == 4)`, avoiding boxing and eliminating ambiguity between `int` and `long`. That doesn’t work with `null` IDs, just like calling `equals` on `null` wouldn’t work, but who said that `null` IDs should be supported? I’d rather say, if there are `null` IDs, let them fail as early as possible. Otherwise, you’d have to swap the objects, i.e. `Long.valueOf(4).equals(a.getId())`, but I wouldn’t do it.

Comment: @Holger ask me this an interview question and I would have failed it... I thought that `a -> a.getId() == 4` would try to compare a `Long` with an `Integer`, but the compiler promotes `4` to `Long`, I was seriously not expecting that :|

Comment: You can not compare `Long` with `Integer`, the compiler would reject that. To get that problem of different boxed types, at least one of the two side must have a more abstract reference compile-time type, like `Object` or `Number`. But if at least one side of the `==` operator is a primitive numeric type, the comparison will be done numerically, using primitive types including numeric promotion. An even more counter-intuitive example would be `Object o = false? Long.valueOf(4): Integer.valueOf(42);` which still is subject to binary numeric promotion, so `o` will be `42` of type `Long`.

Comment: @Holger holly crap!